# React Web Component not bring over react styling

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, web-component

I have a simple web component that wraps a react generic table component.  When rendered in react, the table has the correct styling, I am using tailwind in the generic table component.  However, when wrapped in a web component, the web component correctly renders the generic table component and its functionality, but fails to bring over any of the styling.  I am using vite as the build tool.  I must be missing a config somewhere that is preventing the css from coming over.  I found a plugin for tailwind, but according to the documentation, vite now includes tailwind and the plugin is not needed.

Below is my vite config.

```html
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

import viteTsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { join } from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/web-components-test',
  define: {
    'process.env': {},
  },
  plugins: [
    dts({
      entryRoot: 'src',
      tsConfigFilePath: join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.lib.json'),
      skipDiagnostics: true,
    }),
    react(),
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      root: '../../',
    }),
  ],

  // Configuration for building your library.
  // See: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points.
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      name: 'web-components-test',
      fileName: 'index',
      // Change this to the formats you want to support.
      // Don't forgot to update your package.json as well.
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // External packages that should not be bundled into your library.
      external: [],
    },
  },
});
```

Any help on figuring out why the styling is being dropped would be greatly appreciated.